# error in route enhancers since TYPO3 9.5.18

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x

until TYPO3 9.5.17 the following route enhancer worked:

```
keywords:
  limitToPages:
    - 3735
  type: Plugin
  routePath: '/{uid}'
  namespace: tx_plkeywords_pi1
  requirements:
    uid: '[0-9]{1,3}'
  aspects:
    uid:
      type: PersistedAliasMapper
      tableName: tx_plkeywords_keywords
      routeFieldName: slug
```

The URL looks like this:

```
https://mydomain.de/mypage/?tx_plkeywords_pi1%5Buid%5D=376&cHash=385abdf54fe3c2617c617af32e5a5c1c
```

The error message:

Parameter "tx_plkeywords_pi1__uid" for route "enhancer_tx_plkeywords_pi1000000002142b4310000000022f8b3c9" must match "[0-9]{1,3}" ("videomarketing" given) to generate a corresponding URL.

The table exists and the entry with uid 376 has in the slugs field the entry "videomarketing". I don`t understand what is wrong with this code.

Any help appreciated ... !
Peter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are checking the slug field `routeFieldName: slug`, where "videomarketing" is coming from. On the other hand you restrict the slug to be numeric with `[0-9]{1,3}`.

The question is, what do you want in your slug?

1. If you want the UID to be displayed, you don't need the `aspects` part as the UID is still given in the URL.
2. If you want to use the `slug`, you need to remove the requirements from `uid`. Maybe you should rename the variable to maybe "keyword" as "uid" is misleading.